# Update git mirror without pruning local branches following a specific pattern

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-mirror

I have to update frequently a mirror of a git repository on Github.
In the meantime, I created branches following a specific pattern (let's say `foo-[1-9]+[0-9]*`) on my local mirror. These branches were created at a given tag and contains internal patches.

I would like to update my mirror frequently and get an exact copy of Github's repository + the branches containing internal patches.

At the time I created the mirror, let's assume the state of Github's repository is the below:

```
      C---D branchA
     /
A---B---E---F master
        \
         G---H branchB

v0.1 --> F
```

We use the software at tag **v0.1** and we created patches for some reasons to fix the build or the software. The state of the local repository is now:

```
      C---D branchA
     /
A---B---E---F master
        \   \
         \   I---J foo-1
          \
           G---H branchB

v0.1 --> F
foo-1 has been created and host patches for v0.1
```

In the meantime, new commits, branches appeared on Github and development branches were merged and then deleted. The state of Github's repository is now :

```
                          J'---K branchC
                         /
A---B---E---F---C---D---I' master
            \
             G---H branchB

v0.1 --> F
v0.2 --> D
branchB has been rebased
branchC has been created
branchA has been merged into master and then deleted
```

At first I clone the mirror.

`git clone --mirror ${url_local_repo}`

Then I add Github's repository as remote.

`git remote add --mirror=fetch github ${url_github_repo}`

Finally I fetch the changes from github.

```
git fetch --tags --prune github
   From ${url_github_repo}                                                                                     
    x [deleted]         (none)     -> branchA                                                     
    x [deleted]         (none)     -> foo-1                                                                                                               
    * [new branch]      branchC    -> branchC
    E..F                branchB    -> branchB
    F..I'               master     -> master
```

`foo-1` is deleted but I want to keep it.
I tried to screen the fetch using glob but it does not work.

```
git fetch --dry-run --prune github '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/[!f][!o][!o]*'
fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/[!f][!o][!o]*'
```

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

There is (currently at least) no way to combine a fetch mirror (which really means the fetch refspec is `+refs/*:refs/*` with `--prune` and achieve what you want.

The refspec strings are not true globs: the only pattern character allowed is `*`.  In older versions of Git, `*` must subsume characters surrounded by slashes as well, though this restriction was relaxed in Git 2.6.0 (via [commit `8d3981ccbed9fc211b4e67105015179d9d2a5692`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d3981ccbed9fc211b4e67105015179d9d2a5692).

The `--prune` code basically works by detecting that some ref name-space is the target of a pattern, and that there is no matching source reference to feed into the pattern.  So as long as the source pattern is `refs/*` or `refs/heads/*`, Git will prune any name that does not have a source coming from the other repository.

What you could do is *avoid* `--prune` (or any of its equivalents), and write your own code, in whatever language you prefer, to scan the result of `git ls-remote` plus the result of `git for-each-ref` to decide which references to delete.  Use `git update-ref` to delete them as appropriate.